# Express.js - How to serve index.html from a Webpack bundle?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, express, webpack

I have a repo very similar to [this one](https://github.com/FrozenPandaz/ng-universal-demo). I am aware this is cutting edge since it uses Angular `4.0.0-rc.1`.

Webpack builds two bundles in a `dist` folder, named `server.js` and `client.js`.

My webpack config:

```
const webpack = require('webpack');
const ngtools = require('@ngtools/webpack');
const path = require('path');
const webpackMerge = require('webpack-merge');

const serverConfig = {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/main.server.ts'),
    devtool: 'source-map',
    context: __dirname,
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['.ts', '.js']
    },
    target: 'node',
    output: {
        path: 'dist',
        filename: 'server.js'
    },
    plugins: [
        new ngtools.AotPlugin({
            tsConfigPath: path.join(__dirname, 'tsconfig.json'),
        })
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.ts$/,
                loader: '@ngtools/webpack',
            },
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: 'raw-loader'
            },
            {
                test: /\.scss$/,
                exclude: [
                    /\.unit.scss$/,
                    path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'assets')
                ],
                use: [
                    {
                        loader: 'raw-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'postcss-loader'
                    },
                    {
                        loader: 'sass-loader',
                        options: {
                            includePaths: [path.resolve(__dirname, "./src/assets/styles")]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
};

const clientConfig = webpackMerge({}, serverConfig, {
    entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src/main.browser.ts'),
    output: {
        filename: 'client.js'
    },
    target: 'web'
});

module.exports = [clientConfig, serverConfig];
```

Now, I'd like to add a very simple `express` server and serve the `index.html` file, such that Angular can pick up everything from there (the usual with SPA's).

So I build my express server like so:

```
import * as express from 'express';
import * as path from 'path';
let app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'html');
app.set('views', 'src');

app.use('/', express.static('dist', { index: false }));

app.get('*', (req, res, next) => {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});
app.listen(8000, () => {
    console.log("listening on localhost:8000 (non-universal)");
});
```

But because webpack bundles everything into my two bundles, there is no `index.hml` file in my dist folder.

How would I serve the `index.html` inside the Webpack bundle from Express?

Comment: express is looking for the index.html file in the current folder (__dirname) - is the index file located in the same folder ? if not , try specifying an absolute path to the index.html file in res.sendFile

Comment: yes, the index.html is located in the same folder next to the server file.

Comment: I came across this question while searching for a similar solution. One option is to include your file in the webpack build. Install https://github.com/webpack-contrib/file-loader and require the file in your script. ```require("file-loader?name=index.html!./index.html");```